# PLSQL using table default value in procedure default parameters while inserting

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a procedure to insert values in a table. My table has default values for certain fields. I want the same defaults in my procedure without manually typing it in my procedure. eg

```
create table products
(
    prod_id number primary key,
    stock number default 0
);
```

My procedure declaration:

```
create procedure insert_product
(
    prod_id number,
    stock number default products.stock.default
);
```

But I get:

> Error(58,99): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEFAULT" when
>   expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior The symbol " was inserted before "DEFAULT" to continue.

I tried:

```
stock number default );

stock number default products.stock );
```

But they give errors too. Can the table's default value be accessed by the procedure without typing it explicitly in the procedure ? I know

`stock number default 0 );` works fine.

I am new to PLSQL so forgive me if it's a silly question.

Comment: First of all, in order for a variable to be of the same data type as a table's column, you declare it as follows: `var_name table.column_name%type`. Secondly, PL/SQL variable cannot inherit default value of a table's column. In order for a column to be assigned a default value upon insertion you either omit it or use `default` keyword in the `values()` clause of  your `insert into` statement.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thanks. I was using best practices like stock products.stock%type, naming my constraints and adding comments to column names when needed. I omitted them here for removing clutter. So defaults cannot be inherited. ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a private procedure within your main procedure and achieve this. Please check below: Please see that the code is just an example and not tested.

```
create or replace procedure abc 
as
v_num number;
 --Private Proc to Main procedure abc
 Procedure insert_product ( prod_id number,
                            stock number )
 Is
 begin
  <you logic>;

 end;

Begin

  select stock
  into v_num
  from products
  where <condition>;

  insert_product(PROD_ID,v_num); 

End ;
```

Comment: As I understand, I should check if value is provided for stock in outer procedure. If not, then get table defaults and store it in v_num. Then call the nested procedure to do the actual insert into table. I have 2 issues: 1) again, how to get the table's default field value 2) It is overly complicated way for such a simple task. Can we do it in a simpler way ?

Comment: There is no need to check as this will defeat the purpose of assigning some default value. Once you create a table with default column value,if nothing is inserted to that column, the default value will automatically be populated. In the above example and simply picking the value of stock in my main proc which is anyways going to be default value in case of nothing inserted, and then passing it to my procedure.